# Can a Azure Boards Burndown Charts look at bugs/requirement estimations, rather than just tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am wishing to configure the Sprint Burndown Chart to consider the estmation values assigned to bugs & requirements.

Is this possible or does it only consider the work item type of 'task'?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a Azure Boards Burndown Charts look at bugs/requirement estimations, rather than just tasks?

The answer is **yes**.

When you switch to the Burndown Trend, there is an drop-down menu under the `Backlogs/Work Items`, which you can select the bugs or requirements(for CMMI projects):

[image]

Hope this helps.